# Maximum x-intercept with a parabola and differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics, parametric

I know how to find extrema of a function, however, I'm wondering how calculus would approach finding the maximum x-intercept achieved given a parametric function representing a parabola (or at least the first derivative so that the max distance achieved has a derivative of zero).

I was using a parametric equation for representing the path of a projectile.

$$x=v_0\cos(\theta)t$$
$$y=v_0\sin(\theta)t+\frac{1}{2}(-9.8)\cos(t)$$

I thought initially to do parametric differentiation, but that wouldn't help find max x-intercepts. The goal would be to show that the max range is when $\theta$ is $45\unicode{xb0}$ through showing that the max x-intercept of the parabola is when $\theta$ equals $45\unicode{xb0}$. Is this achievable through calculus? Maybe does it have to do with the max x-coordinate of the vertex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be

$$x=v_0\cos(\theta)t$$

$$y=v_0\sin(\theta)t+\frac{1}{2}(-9.8) t^2$$

$\dot  x=v_0\cos(\theta)$ velocity makes projectile to travel to x $\rightarrow \infty $

To find $ x_{max}$ at starting height just let $y=0$ in the equation of parabolic trajectory.

To find maximum height reached set $\dot y = 0 $ treating $\theta$ temporarily constant and then next treat it as a  variable for differentiation, getting $45^0.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please explain what you mean about your statement about making projectile travel to infinity in the x direction? And would the equation of parabolic trajectory just be y?

Comment: Suppose you are on a mountain top and a deep cliff below.The $x$ component goes on and on until projectile hits land at a  point far away.

Comment: That makes sense. However, just because object is in the air for different amount of time, it's horizontal velocity component varies. So I'm still confused on how to approach this.

Comment: $ \dot  x=v_0\cos(\theta) $ is constant as stated.